# How to remove this line (In the picture) form the terminal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rbenv

I have just uninstalled the `rbenv` from my ubuntu 16.04, and now if I am opening the Terminal I am getting this:

[image]

How can I remove this?

Answer (score 1):

Remove it and its references from your `.bashrc` or `.profile` in your home directory. Use your default editor to edit `~/.bashrc`. For instance...

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Or you could just use this command if you're note sure what an editor is:

```
sed -i '/rbenv/ d' ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I found that on the Internet that I have to remove this `.bashrc` and `.profile` , but where I will find this?

Comment: @shashiverma it's in your home directory, see my updates

Comment: Can you help me with this one also `sudo: /etc/sudoers.d is world writable` I get this, whenever I run any sudo command in Terminal, and there is a lock symbol on my most of the folders of computer like on dev, home, proc,  srv,  sys, var.

Comment: It's a warning that the directory that specifies who can control you computer absolutely (`/etc/sudoers.d`) has inappropriately lax permissions. You need to change the permissions on that folder so that only root can edit it. For instance `sudo chmod -R 700 /etc/sudoers.d` and `sudo chown -R root:root /etc/sudoers.d`

Comment: So, should I run this command, and how I will come to know that this issue has been resolved.

Comment: if I update my ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04, then can this issue be solved?

Comment: You might submit a question to superuser.com to get answers, this isn't a good place to have this discussion

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1379292/ubuntu-can-i-resolve-this-issue-sudo-etc-sudoers-d-is-world-writable-by-up now please help me, this is my office's system. :(